# Why is the Angular digest loop different on UI events, $timeout and $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been working on a lib for Angular, using 1.2.27, and to my surprise I am looking at this result:

```
$scope.myClickMethod = function () {
  $scope.$$phase; // $apply
  $scope.$apply(); // Gives digest error, of course
};

$timeout(function () {
  $scope.$$phase; // null
  $scope.$apply(); // Does not give a digest error
});

$http.get('/').then(function () {
  $scope.$$phase; // $digest
  $scope.$apply(); // Gives digest error
});
```

The problem is that you can not identify that a digest loop is ready to run when using $timeout, $http etc. only ng-clicks etc. My questions is... why are they different? I thought Angular did something like this in both cases:

```
$scope.myClickMethod = function AngularWrapper () {
  $rootScope.$apply(function myOriginalMethod () {
    // My code
  });
};

$timeout(function AngularWrapper () {
  $rootScope.$apply(function myOriginalTimoutFunction () {
    // My code
  });
});
```

Why is $$phase = $apply on UI-events, $$phase = $digest on $http and $$phase = null on $timeout? They are all async in nature, it does not make sense that they behave so differently. I am sure there is a perfectly good reason though. Anyone know?

I see that 1.3 has some changes to $http with a new $applyAsync method. Not tested that though.

Answer (score 0):

The `$timeout` callback is called at the end of the digest loop.

So, because you are outside the digest loop, you can call `$apply` and it will recall an entire digest loop.

For the other methods (`ng-click`, `$http`), they are called during the digest loop. So calling `$apply` will give an error because AngularJS doesn't want a digest loop **in** a digest loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but why is it like that? I can not see why they should behave differently. Especially $timeout and $http?

Comment: It's just the way AngularJS works. I think `$timeout` has been created to be called after the digest loop by purpose. Sometime, you just need the digest loop to be finished.

Comment: Hm, I tested $http and it actually is something in between. See updated question. It does give error, but also a $digest value to $$phase. I wanna know why! :-D

Comment: Hehe, updated question again. I have a stubborn need to know why they behave differently. I know they do behave differently and there is probably a good reason, but what is that good reason?